# How can I make the `cal` tool in OSX highlight the current day?

Tags: osx, cal

In Ubuntu and Fedora, when I type `cal` on the command line I get an ASCII calendar with the current day highlighted.

In OSX, when I type `cal`, I get an ASCII calendar but no day is highlighted.

How can I get the highlighting of the current date in OSX?

Comment: OSX and Linux use different implementations of cal.  I imagine OSX's isn't written to highlight the current day.

Comment: @AndyDalton, I just noticed after your comment that OSX's version is 5 years older (2004 vs 2009) based on the man page.

Comment: @merlin2011 OS X uses “BSD cal” while Linux will be using “GNU cal”. Two different implementations rather than versions 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following prints the current date with a reversed field which is replaced in cal by sed.

```
ptd=$(date -j +%d)
ctd=$(printf "\033[0;7m"$ptd"\033[0m")
cal | sed 's/'"$ptd"'/'"$ctd"'/'
```

Comment: Replace the sequences of escape codes with (the output of) `tput smso` and `tput rmso` and you'll have something that works correctly when it's piped to a file, or even used on a different type of terminal.

Comment: Does not work for single digit dates.  Example: today, `date -j +%d` prints `04` which does not appear in output of `cal`.

Answer (score 4):

I've tried ubuntu, fedora, slackware, and netBSD and all the cal's automatically highlight the current day. However, I know some cals don't auto highlight, and either way, this does work:

```
cal | grep -C 6 --color -e " $(date +%e)" -e "^$(date +%e)"
```

Although I can't test on OS X as I do not have access to it.

Comment: This works for me in OS X 10.11 (El Capitan Public Beta 5). Today's date is highlighted in red.

Comment: or: `cal | grep -E --color "(\b$(date +%d)\b|$)"`

Comment: Just tried it on OS X (10.11.6). Works nicely.